# Help understand this proof: unit disk on plane have no finite paradoxical decomposition

Tags: group-theory, geometry, elementary-set-theory

I am working through the note [here](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/01/08/245b-notes-2-amenability-the-ping-pong-lemma-and-the-banach-tarski-paradox-optional/#more-1354). I have been stuck at Proposition #5 proof for a while because I can't understand the last part. Specifically, the proposition said that "The unit disk $D$ in ${\Bbb R}^2$ is not finitely $SO(2) \ltimes {\Bbb R}^2$-paradoxical". I can't understand starting from inequality (7) till the end how each of these inequality work.

If anyone can provide a detailed explanation, or link me to an alternative proof, it would be much appreciated.